# Is there a way that I can allow a incrementing counter to display a image on the index page when even and another when false. In the body is my try

Tags: blazor

@page "/counter"

## Counter

Current count: @currentCount

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me

@code {
private int currentCount = 0;

```
private void IncrementCount()
{
    currentCount++;
    if (currentCount % 2 == 0)
    {
        <img src="~/Images/black_atlasian_mode copy.png" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Images/teal_atlasian_mode copy.png" />
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. Image hase to be in html part, you are changing src only:

```
Current count: @currentCount

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me
</button>   
<img src="@src" />
@code { 
    
    private int currentCount = 0;
    string src = "~/Images/black_atlasian_mode copy.png";

private void IncrementCount()
{
    currentCount++;
    if (currentCount % 2 == 0)
    {
        src = "~/Images/black_atlasian_mode copy.png";
    }
    else
    {
         src = "~/Images/teal_atlasian_mode copy.png";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was able to take your code and make it work.  @page "/counter" to the top.  I wasn't able to get the images to work until I put them directly into the wwwroot.  I was think that if I added a Folder called Images under the wwwroot and place them there it would.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, images has to me somewhere inside the wwwroot. The rest of the code is not accessible. If you add additional folder it will make your path as this: `src="images/image.png"`. If you have a lot of images and you don't want to drag them everywhere, use something like Blob Storage and track the urls in db..